# Word Searching in dictionary implemented using text/binary file not using sql or any database

Tags: java, search

I want to build a dictionary without using any database application.  I also want to store word in text/binary file.  How can I improve searching if a file contains millions of records.

Comment: Any reason for that? Seems very inefficient

Comment: database string search mechanism is also very inefficient.

Comment: can i use multiple index which is also store in different file like for word starting from 'A' the index file contain fist record position same as for other alphabets

Comment: If you want simplicity - use H2 (for one thread application) or SQLite. If You want fast search look for lucene/solr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the concept of [Inverted Indexing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverted_index). It could go like this:

- Sort the file.
- For every character in the alphabet keep the first and last line that a particular character appears in a certain position.
- For a certain word get all the ranges and calculate the intersection. The sequence matters. If the intersection is empty keep the previous one. If in the end the intersection is empty, the word doesn't exist.

For example:
You have calculated the range (first and last line) that character `a` appears in the first position of a word. The same for the second position and so on and so forth. You do the same for all the characters of the alphabet.

Let's assume you want the word "apple".
You find the range that `a` appears in the first position (Set A). `p` in the second (Set B) and third position(Set C), `l` in the forth (Set D) and `e` (Set E) in the fifth. You have 5 ranges.
You calculate the intersection of these five ranges like this:

1. A intersect B = K. If K is empty then K = A.
2. K intersect C = Y. If Y is empty then Y = K...

This leaves you a much smaller range when you hit the disk. Basically with this you have an estimation of where in the file this word is located.

This approach is safe regarding memory. The size of the structure depends on the size of the alphabet and on the size of the biggest word you have in the dictionary. Of course you will have to take into consideration that the data represented by the intersection can be bigger than the memory. In this case you will have to load the data in chunks.

It's very expensive to add or delete a word from the dictionary, because you will have to sort and recalculate the index. In order to avoid doing the calculation every time, you can save your index in another file (serialize).